# Why is the data from my json file not loading when I open my app again after closing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to save the "reminders" added to a list, in my app to a json file. My code currently successfully creates a new json file called reminders and saves data into it. But when closing and opening the app again, the data doesnt load. I have know I have the function made for loading the file, does anyone know what I missed in my code?

code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        // Set up the Numeric Up Down control for minutes
        numMinutes.Minimum = 0;
        numMinutes.Maximum = 59;

        // Set up the Numeric Up Down control for seconds
        numSeconds.Minimum = 0;
        numSeconds.Maximum = 59;

        // Load the reminders from the JSON file
        LoadRemindersFromJsonFile();
    }

    private void notiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the number of minutes until the reminder from the NumericUpDown control
        int minutes = (int)numMinutes.Value;
        int seconds = (int)numSeconds.Value;

        // Get the time difference
        TimeSpan timeDifference = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)numMinutes.Value) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)numSeconds.Value);

        // Set up a timer to check for the reminder time
        Timer reminderTimer = new Timer();

        // Check if the time difference is greater than zero
        if (timeDifference.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
        {
            // Calculate the reminder time
            DateTime reminderTime = DateTime.Now.Add(timeDifference);

            // Set the timer interval
            reminderTimer.Interval = (int)timeDifference.TotalMilliseconds;

            reminderTimer.Tick += ReminderTimer_Tick;

            // Start the timer
            reminderTimer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(new Form {TopMost = true }, "Please enter a value greater than zero.", "Invalid Input");
        }
    }

    private void ReminderTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Select a random note from the panelNotes.Controls collection
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(notesPanel.Controls.Count);
        Note selectedNote = (Note)notesPanel.Controls[index];

        // Stop the timer
        Timer reminderTimer = (Timer)sender;
        reminderTimer.Stop();

        // Show the reminder message box
        var messageBox = MessageBox.Show(this, selectedNote.title.Text + "\n\n" + selectedNote.body.Text, "Reminder");

        // Set up the timer for the next reminder
        TimeSpan timeDifference = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)numMinutes.Value) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)numSeconds.Value);
        reminderTimer.Interval = (int)timeDifference.TotalMilliseconds;
        reminderTimer.Start();

        // Reset the form for the next reminder
        //ResetForm();

    }

    private void ResetForm()
    {
        // Reset the numeric up down controls
        numMinutes.Value = 0;
        numSeconds.Value = 0;
    }

    private Point nextNoteLocation = new Point(0, 10);
    private void addNoteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Note note = new Note();
        note.Location = nextNoteLocation;
        this.notesPanel.Controls.Add(note);
        nextNoteLocation.Y += note.Height + 10;

        reminders.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(DateTime.Now, note.title.Text + "\n\n" + note.body.Text));

        SaveRemindersToJsonFile();
    }

    private void SaveRemindersToJsonFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // Serialize the reminders list to JSON
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reminders);

            // Write the JSON to the file
            File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving reminders: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void LoadRemindersFromJsonFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if the JSON file exists
            if (File.Exists(jsonFilePath))
            {
                // Read the contents of the JSON file
                string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

                // Deserialize the JSON into the reminders list
                reminders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>>(json);

                // Add the reminders to the notesPanel
                foreach (var reminder in reminders)
                {
                    Note note = new Note();
                    note.title.Text = reminder.Item2;
                    note.body.Text = reminder.Item2;
                    note.Location = nextNoteLocation;
                    notesPanel.Controls.Add(note);
                    nextNoteLocation.Y += note.Height + 10;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading reminders: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: does it throw exception? are you sure that there is a text exists in your file?

Comment: What does `jsonFilePath` point to?

Comment: Also, when you debug the code, which path is it going down when trying to load the file?

Comment: @stuartd the jsonFilePath points to: private string jsonFilePath = "reminders.json"; which is supposed to be the path of the file. and the "reminders.json" file goes to the same folder as the Application exe file. Bin > Release > net5.0-windows.

Comment: @AhmedAlayat yes, the files has text: [{"Item1":"2023-04-23T10:41:55.7275458-05:00","Item2":"Title\n\nBody"},{"Item1":"2023-04-23T10:41:56.145127-05:00","Item2":"Title\n\nBody"},{"Item1":"2023-04-23T14:51:33.2222785-05:00","Item2":"Title\n\nBody"},{"Item1":"2023-04-23T14:51:33.3007868-05:00","Item2":"Title\n\nBody"}] if that helps and no there is no exceptions thrown

Comment: at any point does your code break? loading the file? does json object have this string value? or does it break on deserializaion?

Comment: @AhmedAlayat im not sure if my code breaks, but the code I provided is basically the entire code the app is currently running off of. Not too familiar with the .net winforms. I assumed that LoadRemindersFromJsonFile(); in the constructor should be doing the job but not sure if the things stored in my json file isnt working or the function. The text is everything stored in the json file currently.

Comment: I mean "are you sure that your json file is loaded??" because if not there is a problem with your path

Comment: @AhmedAlayat i do not believe my file is loaded. how could i know if there is a problem with my path?

Comment: show a message if the path doesn't exists
if (File.Exists(jsonFilePath))
{}else{//message here}

Comment: @AhmedAlayat i can confirm it is not a problem with my path. i removed the try and catch statements and just left the if else alone and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: can you also check if the json string object has a value? Message.Show(json);

Comment: also check if the json string is deserialized properly. MessageBox.Show(reminders.Count.ToString());

Comment: @AhmedAlayat showing the "json" just has the same text value as what i put above, which is just the items and their values.  reminders.count shows a value of 4.

Comment: That means that your file is loaded and deserialized properly. notesPanel.Controls.Add(note); maybe there is a problem with the control 'note' itself